# How do you save multiple fields to one row or objectId in Parse using Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

[image]

I'm getting the above layout from Parse.  What I want is vid 1, 2, and 3 to be in the same row; associated with same object ID.  How can I do this?  My ultimate goal is to easily retrieve 10 video dictionary's per user on a table view.  Will any of this make a difference?  I'm saving like this.....

```
videoDict = ["id":videoId, "title":vidTitleText, "description":vidDescription, "image":vidIMG]
        let videoSave = PFObject(className:"UserVideos")
        videoSave["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
        videoSave["vid\(saveValueLBL.text!)"] = videoDict
        videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                print("Succesfull")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `let videoSave = PFObject(className:"UserVideos")` you are creating a new videoSave object each time. you need to move that outside of your loop so that you're accessing the same object each time instead of making a new one. However, the way you currently have your code set up you'll run into problems, because each object can only have one synchronous action called on it (in this case, your save), so the second, third, maybe even all the way to the 10th save may not occur because it needs the first one to finish before the next one can be called. You need to create your object outside your loop, run the loop, then call the save at the end to make sure it isn't saving until all of the data is updated.

If this isn't all inside of a loop, you need to get the videoSave object back each time, perhaps by storing it onto your user, and then fetching it from the user object.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything outside the loop and keep just the code below inside the loop:

```
videoDict = ["id":videoId, "title":vidTitleText, "description":vidDescription, "image":vidIMG]
videoSave["vid\(saveValueLBL.text!)"] = videoDict
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand although I saved information in Parse as a Dictionary this is in fact an invalid data type.  That's why I'm having trouble retrieving because Parse doesn't recognize the info.